# Is the Whitney topology finer or coincide with uniform topology for codomain is $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

Let $C^{r}(U,\mathbb{R})$ be the space of $C^{r}$ functions from open subset $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $0\leq r<\infty$. This space can equipped with the Whitney topology(or strong topology), is this topology finer than the uniform topology(supremum norm as a metric), or actually coincide?

**Edit**
It seems that there is no way to compare this two topology in the above setting. If we only focus on subspace $C^{r}_{b}(U,\mathbb{R})$, the space of $C^{r}$ and bounded function, so that supremum norm can be defined. Can we compare their topology?

Comment: How are you defining the sup norm? The domain is the issue, not the codomain.

Comment: I have edited the question. Now the domain is just open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: There are still unbounded functions on such a domain.

Comment: I think @Ken. Wong wanted to ask about bounded open subsets $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

This question is discussed in detail in section 1.7 of the book:

Eldering, Jaap. Normally hyperbolic invariant manifolds: the noncompact case. Vol. 2. Atlantis Press, 2013.

Here is a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.1310.pdf), and here is the final paragraph of section 1.7:

> We conclude that the $C^k_b$-topologies induced by our uniform norms are not equivalent to either the weak or strong Whitney topology, because the weak topology
> allows arbitrary behavior of functions outside compact sets, while the strong
> topology completely restricts that behavior. Our norms allow moderate variations at infinity. In general, ‘moderate behavior’ is not well-defined on a general
> noncompact manifold, as it depends on the choice of charts. In the setting of
> bounded geometry, though, the uniform, metric structure makes this behavior
> unambiguous; we can restrict to normal coordinate charts and consider ‘moderate
> behavior’ with respect to these. Note that these topologies are equivalent on
> compact domains.